# how to apply BREAK for Itertools count in List Comprehensions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

if this is duplicate, already answered then sorry, i didn't came across this question

as i was reading itertools count, generating an iterator using for loop is easy, and i was trying to do that in list comprehension but i am facing this problem

```
from itertools import *
```

by using for loop

```
for x in itertools.count(5,2):
    if x > 20:
        break
    else: 
        print(x)
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19
```

i tried to do this in list comprehension

```
[x if x<20 else break for x in count(5,2)]
  File "<ipython-input-9-436737c82775>", line 1
    [x if x<20 else break for x in count(5,2)]
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i tried with islice method and i got the answer

```
[x for x in itertools.islice(itertools.count(5),10)]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

without using islice method, how can I exit(using break or any thing) by using only count method?

additionally how to implement `break` in `list comprehensions`?

Comment: Why don't you like `islice`? There's definitely no `break` inside list comprehension, but there's [`takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile).

Comment: Why don't you use `range(5, 20, 2)` or `range(5, 15)` ?

Comment: it's not about liking, i just want to know that "can i do in this way or not?"
@bereal

Comment: i can use range, as i was reading itertools, i tried to do with itertools @falsetru

Answer (score 7):

There's no `break` inside list comprehensions or generator expressions, but if you want to stop on a certain condition, you can use [`takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile, count
>>> list(takewhile(lambda x: x < 20, count(5, 2)))
[5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
```

Comment: You can `list(takewhile(int(20).__gt__, count(5, 2)))` to remove the ugly lambda and it will be quite a but faster.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham faster yes, but I would perhaps question the comparative ugliness.

Comment: I meant ugly as much for the overhead as the visual representation, a lambda with any functional code is the kiss of death for performance which is generally what you are trying to achieve when using itertools, map, filter etc.

Comment: @avimatta You can also accept the answer, this is the greatest "Thank you, it works!"

Comment: @PadraicCunningham can you tell me          "a lambda with any functional code is the kiss of death for performance?"

Comment: @PadraicCunningham there's nothing ugly about lambda. It's fine.